# DB snapshots in RDS

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a scenario where there are multiple databases in a single RDS instance. Let's call them A, B & C.

1. Is it possible to take a snapshot of just one database (say A or B) & not the entire RDS instance?
2. How can we recover just a single database from the snapshot of that particular database?

From what I have read & understood, RDS supports ***Automated Backups & Database Snapshots***, both of which take a snapshot of the entire RDS instance rather than at the more granular (DB) level.

Comment: No, this is not possible. It's a volume-level snapshot, which means that the backup doesn't know or care about the database stored in it.

Comment: You need to make a dump of the db in your localhost or an EC2  you want and restore when needed. As from snapshot, you need to create a db, and make a dump ..